# Is there any predictable issue in using the same working-tree/working-copy files under both VCS: bzr and git?

Tags: git, github, bazaar

I.e, I want to have .bzr and .git in the same* folder and add/commit/push/pull with git and bzr independently from each other to their respective repos.
My main fear is that one (maybe bzr) becomes aware of the other's "activities".

It seems that there are no issues, but hearing from someone that already tried it, could makes me more confortable.

*obs.: this has nothing to do with bzr-git plugin, specially because the "main" repo is bzr, and my secondary repo will be git, because of github needs.*

*-> "same folder", actually .git in a subfolder

Comment: Use one or the other. Anything else will just get you all confused with what you did (or did not) check in.

Comment: Maybe the problems will arise when pulling from one or another repo.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you add `.bzr`, and make bazaar ignores `.git` directory, both systems should work correctly.

You should however look into the [git-bzr script](https://github.com/termie/git-bzr-ng) (different than the bzr-git plugin), it apparently can do bi-directional git and bzr operations.